# How to DROP a function in postgres extension upgrade script with required cleanup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

Suppose we have a hypothetical extension named as xyz with version 1.0. It has `xyz--1.0.sql` and `xyz.c` file. I have declared function named fun() in `xyz--1.0.sql` file and its definition in `xyz.c` file.

Now I wanted to drop this function in the next upgrade i.e `xyz--1.0--1.1` so I will use `DROP FUNCTION fun();` in it and remove the definition from `xyz.c` file.

Here my doubt is wouldn't `xyz--1.0` will complain about missing definition of fun() and if yes how can I clean up my function definition in `xyz.c` file?

Comment: `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fun();` (Untested, but certainly suppresses complaints.)

Comment: Hi Erwin, I guess you didn't get my question, my concern is, if I will remove the function fun from next update still it will be present in earlier version which will demand some C definition. Now if I will remove that C definition as I have dropped the fun() in new version wouldn't there would be errors?

Comment: I would have to look into extension upgrade dynamics myself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave the function in the `xyz.c` file forever, otherwise people who choose not to update the extension will have a problem.

You could be rude and ship version 2 without the function and without `xyz--1.0.sql` (so that you can no longer install version 1.0, only upgrade from it), but you had better make clear to the users that they need to

```
ALTER EXTENSION xyz UPDATE;
```

otherwise they will be facing ugly errors.